# How to test with Math.random in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I have a function that will select a random value between a min and a max value. So when I have a test where I test that the value fall between the min and max value. But as there where some failures in my app the test passed some times and some times fails due to the randomness.

Would it be a good idea to override/mock `Math.random()` to return 0 and 1 and test that my value is same as max or min value? Or are there better ways to test randomness in JavaScript?

Here is the function that will be used to create the random number:

```
function constrain(min, max){
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the second-to-last sentence... what would it help to let `Math.random()` return either `0` or `1`? I think you should provide some more information, and examples, and your code. Maybe your test is flawed.

Comment: I add the function. Passing 0/1 would return the min or max value I've passed, cause this are the min/max values `Math.random()` will return. So in my test instead of testing that the value returned is between min and max I can check if its equal min or max.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[SinonJS](http://sinonjs.org/) is a JavaScript [mocking framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) which integrates with all of the major JavaScript Unit Testing frameworks.  The adapters will take care of 'reverting' any stubs / mocks that you create during your tests.

```
// Stub out Math.random so it always returns '4' (chosen by fair dice roll)
sinon.stub(Math, 'random').returns(4);

// Double check that it worked.
equal(Math.random(), 4, "http://xkcd.com/221/");
```

Comment: btw. `Math.random` returns only values between 0 and 1, so 4 doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

Generally your tests should pass for all possible values of your non-deterministic code. Maybe have a loop in your test where you do the test say 100 times. That will catch more failures without changing the application code. What you suggested is also an option.

Answer (score 2):

Preferrably, you should have no [random](http://www.xkcd.com/221/) element in your test at all. You should feed your method known values, so that you can determine if the result is exactly what you excpect.

If you have random values, you would have to test the method a lot of times, and you are still not sure that you get the exact result that you want, only that you get something in the right range.

If you for example use the current date in your code (`new Date()`), then you should provide your method with known dates when testing, otherwise your test will only show that the method works right now. Tomorrow it might fail.

---

#### Edit:

However, I can tell you right away that your method doesn't work well. You should use the `floor` method instead of `round`, otherwise the lowest and highest values will occur half as often as the other values:

```
function constrain(min, max){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}
```

Comment: That why I wanna mock math.random.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle: Yes, and in Javascript you can do that. Another alternative is to assign the random function to a variable, i.e. `var getRandom = Math.random;` and use that in your ocde, then you can change the value of the variable rather than the built in property.